# QT Creator Community run window closes immediately

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

Sorry for the n00b question.
My program crashes immediately when I hit `ctrl + R` on QT Creator Community, without displaying the message `Hello Qt`. Should I do something like `keep window open` on Windows? I am running Debian with QMake.
Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello Qt\n";
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The headers are useful for further programs I want to write, Please don't suggest to delete them unless it's strictly necessary... thanks!

Comment: You can also use `system("pause")` (Windows specific) This happens only when you run debug mode.

Comment: @andrey.s http://www.stroustrup.com/hello_world.c

Comment: It is necessary to delete the headers because they are irrelevant to this test case. You don't need any besides `<iostream>`. The test case is meant to be minimal and complete. Every line you don't need is a line that detracts from the issue and helps no one. Basically, as long as you have the problem, you should keep removing the code. You'll notice that you don't need the `"cout << "Hello Qt\n"` either: the behavior will be identical, it'll still crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow, reinstalling the C++ compiler and rebooting the system did the work